# Angular2 view not updating after model is set from another component

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, model

I have a simple web app that has an app model and a couple of components. When I update an array that I have in my model the view where that model is being consumed does not update. When I console log the model array I can see the model being updated just not the view. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below please have a look at what I currently have.

**overview.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModel } from '../models/app-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  providers: [AppModel]
})
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public AppModel:AppModel) { }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**app-model.ts**

```
export class AppModel {
  myArray:Array<any> = [];
  constructor(){}
}
```

**overview.component.html** *(This is the view that is not being updated when the model gets updated)*

```
<td *ngFor="let dataItem of AppModel.myArray">
  <span{{ dataItem }}</span>
</td>
```

**This is how I am updating the array in the app model from another component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AppService } from '../services/app.service';
import { AppModel } from '../models/app-model';

@Component({
 selector: 'other-component',
 templateUrl: './other-component.component.html',
 providers: [AppService, AppModel]
})

export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private http: Http, public AppService:AppService,public AppModel:AppModel) {}

private updateModel() :void {
  this.AppModel.myArray = someArray;
}

ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: How do you update `myArray`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated my question to include how I am updating the model.

Comment: Where is `updateModel` being called from?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it's being called from other.component.ts when a user clicks on a button I have wired up to fire updateModel

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added it to the question you might need to refresh

Comment: Use a Subject, like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: There are still too many parts missing to be able to tell what could go wrong.

Comment: the `dataCollected` variable isn't declared qnd not initialized ?

Comment: If you provide `AppModel` on both components, you get a different instance for each component. Is this intentional?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated my question again, I was trying to simplify code to make my question a little easier to process. I added the full version of the what I have. Hopefully this is enough to better assist me. If not I guess I can look into the subject as you mentioned earlier and see if that would help.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer different instances of my app model was not intentional I was not aware that was happening.

Comment: You get an instance per provider. If you add a provider to a component, you get as many instances as you have component instances. Only the component itself and it's children can inject a provider from a component. You either need to provide the service on a common parent component or in `@NgModule()`. With providers only in `@NgModule()` you get a single instance for your whole application.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer adding the app model to providers array in @ngModule() and removing it elsewhere did the trick. Thank you for your time, patience and assistance much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear. You should still consider observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a service you get an instance per provider.
If you add a provider to a component, you get as many service instances as you have component instances. Only the component itself and it's children can inject a provider from a component.
You either need to provide the service on a common parent component or in `@NgModule()`.
With providers only in `@NgModule()` you get a single instance for your whole application